# I want to take the first number from an array and depending on its index put equal amount of 0 next to it

Tags: javascript, algorithm

edit: without giving me too much of the answer to how i can do it in a for loop. Could you give me the logic/pseudocode on how to achieve this? the one part i am stuck at is, ok i know that i have to take the first index number and add array.length-1 zeros to it (2 zeros), but i am confused as to when it arrives at the last index, do i put in a if statement in the for loop?

In the below example 459 would be put in an array [4,5,9]

Now I want to take 4 add two zeros to the end because it has two numbers after it in the array

Then I want to take 5 and add one zero to it because there is one number after it in the array.

then 9 would have no zeros added to it because there are no numbers after it.

So final output would be 400,50,9

how can i best achieve this?

```js
var num=459;

var nexint=num.toString().split("");

var finalint=nexint.map(Number);
var nextarr=[];
```

Comment: what is this? sounds entirely pointless which means it probably homework or a codewars challenge or something.

Comment: this is not helpful at all. this is as far as i got and thus why i ask so i can understand the solution. Where does one go to get help if no one is actually being helpful? this is even tougher for someone who is trying to learn for the first time

Comment: @RogerC I love that site. Makes giving a downvote reason easy.

Comment: @user2763557 The point here is that you have not even tried to create a solution. This site does not exist to write code for you. This site exists to help you with the code **you have already written**, but you have written no code

Comment: there is code up there! the next step is what i am stuck at, i am stuck at the next logical step, so i am here to ask for help or guidance on what i could do next, heck i don't even need the answer i just want a guiding hand so i can figure out the answer. You don't even need to give me the correct code, even just the pseudo code to guide me in the right direction would be so much more helpful to my learning process than stupid link to why you downvoted(no offense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP asked for a solution using loops in a comment above.  Here's one approach with loops:

```
var num = 459
var numArray = num.toString().split('');
var position = numArray.length - 1;
var finalArray = [];
var i;
var j;
for(i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++) {
  finalArray.push(numArray[i]);
  for(j = 0; j < position; j++) {
    finalArray.push(0);
  }
  position--;
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

**The general flow**

Loop over the original array, and on each pass:

- Push the element to the final array
- Then push X number of zeros to the final array.  X is determined by
  the element's position in the original array, so if the original
  array has 3 elements, the first element should get 2 zeros after it. 
  This means X is the original array's length - 1 on the first pass.
- Adjust the variable that's tracking the number of zeros to add before
  making the next pass in the loop.

Comment: Yes, it uses loops, but I personally find this solution harder to understand than any of the others posted here.  That's part of the reason I almost never use `for`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use string's repeat method.

```js
var num=459;
var a = (""+num).split('').map((c,i,a)=>c+"0".repeat(a.length-i-1))
console.log(a);
```

Here's another possible solution using a loop.

```js
var num = 459;
var a = ("" + num).split('');
var ar = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var str = a[i];
  str += "0".repeat(a.length-i-1);
  ar.push(str);
}
console.log(ar);
```

Comment: thank you! in terms of modifying this code, and since my understanding is limited on .map methods/.repeat. Would you be able to assist with achieving this through a for loop?

Comment: @Occam'sRazor sorry let me rephrase without giving me the answer to how i can do it for loop. Could you give me the logic/pseudocode on how to achieve this? the one part i am stuck at is, ok i know that i have to take the first index number and add array.length-1 zeros to it (2 zeros), but i am confused as to when it arrives at the last index, do i put in a if statement in the for loop? sorry if i am confusing.

Comment: @user2763557 Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49801723/edit) your question with that information.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for the values multiplied by `10` and return a new array.

```js
var num = 459,
    result = [...num.toString()].reduce((r, a) => r.map(v => 10 * v).concat(+a), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You mention `reduceRight`, but use `reduce`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, i was thinking about it, but the code is right, the description not. thank you.

Comment: That's always easy to tell when there's a working snippet!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @OccamsRazor's implementation, but with a slightly different API, and laid out for easier readability:

```js
const toParts = n => String(n)
  .split('')
  .map((d, i, a) => d.padEnd(a.length - i, '0'))
  .map(Number)

console.log(toParts(459))
```